# Partial Regex Matching

Tags: python, regex

I am inquiring about partial regex matching in Python.

**For Example:**

If you have a string:

```
string = 'foo bar cat dog elephant barn yarn p n a'
```

And a regex:

```
pattern = r'foo bar cat barn yard p n a f'
```

The following would be true:

- `re.match(pattern, string)` Would return `None`.
- `re.search(pattern, string)` Would also return `None`

Although we can all see that the first part of the pattern matches the first part of the string.

So instead of searching for the entirety of the pattern in the string, is there a way to see what percentage of the string matched the pattern?

Comment: The pattern must be matched **entirely**.  If you want part of it to be optional, use `?`.  Look at python doc (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) or howto (https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html).  For example `pattern = r'foo bar cat( barn yard p n a f)?'`

Comment: I know :). The question was asking **Instead** of searching entirely, is there another way to do it returning a percentage instead of a match.

Comment: You can eventually look at the regex module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex that provides a fuzzy match feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with regular expressions.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
SequenceMatcher(None, string, pattern).ratio()
# => 0.7536231884057971
```

You can even match words rather than characters:

```
SequenceMatcher(None, string.split(), pattern.split()).ratio()
# => 0.7368421052631579
```

Comment: Thank you this is *exactly* what I was looking for!

Comment: Great module, great functionality. Unfortunately, this is only for string patterns, not for regular expressions (i.e. having `?`, `|`, `()` etc.). I'd like to know if it was consumed or failed due to a conflict. If so, how far into the *pattern* did the string go?

Answer (score 6):

**yes, it is possible to do partial regular expression matching**

I was playing around with this idea of partial matches and found this Q during my searches. I found a way to do what I needed and thought I'd post it here.

It's no speed demon. Probably only useful where speed isn't an issue.

This function finds the best partial match for the regular expression and returns the matching text.

```
>>> def partial_match(regex, string, flags=0, op=re.match):
...     """
...     Matches a regular expression to a string incrementally, retaining the
...     best substring matched.
...     :param regex:   The regular expression to apply to the string.
...     :param string:  The target string.
...     :param flags:   re module flags, e.g.: `re.I`
...     :param op:      Either of re.match (default) or re.search.
...     :return:        The substring of the best partial match.
...     """
...     m = op(regex, string, flags)
...     if m:
...         return m.group(0)
...     final = None
...     for i in range(1, len(regex) + 1):
...         try:
...             m = op(regex[:i], string, flags)
...             if m:
...                 final = m.group(0)
...         except re.error:
...             pass
...     return final
...
```

Testing it out:

```
>>> partial_match(r".*l.*?iardvark", "bluebird")
'bluebi'
>>> 
>>> partial_match(r"l.*?iardvark", "bluebird")
>>> # None was returned. Try again with search...
>>> 
>>> partial_match(r"l.*?iardvark", "bluebird", op=re.search)
'luebi'
>>>
>>> string = 'foo bar cat dog elephant barn yarn p n a'
>>> pattern = r'foo bar cat barn yard p n a f'
>>> 
>>> partial_match(pattern, string)
'foo bar cat '
>>> 
>>> partial_match(r".* (zoo){1,3}ran away", "the fox at the "
...                                         "zoozoozoozoozoo is "
...                                         "happy")
'the fox at the zoozoozoo'
```

Behaves as expected. The algorithm keeps trying to match as much of the expression it can to the target string. It continues until the whole expression has been matched up against the target string, retaining the best partial match.

Alright. Now let's see just how slow it really is...

```
>>> import cProfile as cprof, random as rand, re
>>>
>>> # targets = ['lazy: that# fox~ The; little@ quick! lamb^ dog~ ',
>>> #            << 999 more random strings of random length >>]
>>>
>>> words = """The; quick! brown? fox~ jumped, over. the! lazy: dog~
...            Mary? had. a little- lamb, a& little@ lamb^ {was} she... and,,, 
...            [everywhere] that# Mary* went=, the. "lamb" was; sure() (to) be.
...         """.split()
...
>>> targets = [' '.join(rand.choices(words, k=rand.randint(1, 100))) 
...            for _ in range(1000)]
...
>>> exprs   = ['.*?&', '.*(jumped|and|;)', '.{1,100}[\\.,;&#^]', '.*?!', 
...            '.*?dog. .?lamb.?', '.*?@', 'lamb', 'Mary']
...
>>> partial_match_script = """
... for t in targets:
...     for e in exprs:
...         m = partial_match(e, t)
...         """
...
>>> match_script = """
... for t in targets:
...     for e in exprs:
...         m = re.match(e, t)
...         """
... 
>>> cprof.run(match_script)
         32003 function calls in 0.032 seconds
>>>
>>> cprof.run(partial_match_script)
         261949 function calls (258167 primitive calls) in 0.230 seconds
```

*Running it head-to-head with `re.match()` which only has to do regular matches and fails most of the time probably isn't a fair comparison of the function's performance. A better comparison would be against a module that supports fuzzy matching, which I did below.. and the function did okay afterall.*

A more performant solution could possibly be developed using the `re.sre_parse` and/or `re.sre_compile` modules. It looks like all the documentation to go by is in the sources and bits and pieces on the 'net like https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1434/sre_parse

With those modules, I think there may be a way to apply a regex incrementally by tokens, or by subexpressions, rather than by single characters as I've done.

Also, as someone commented, the regex package has fuzzy matching capabilities (https://pypi.org/project/regex/) - but it behaves a little differently and could permit unexpected characters in the partial match.

```
>>> import regex
>>>
>>> regex.match(r"(?:a.b.c.d){d}", "a.b.c", regex.ENHANCEMATCH).group(0)
'a.b.c'
>>> regex.match(r"(?:moo ow dog cat){d}", "moo cow house car").group(0)
'moo c'
>>> regex.match(r"(?:moo ow dog cat){d}", "moo cow house car", 
...             regex.ENHANCEMATCH).group(0)
...
'moo c'
>>> # ^^ the 'c' above is not what we want in the output. As you can see,
>>> # the 'fuzzy' matching is a bit different from partial matching.
>>>
>>> regex_script = """
... for t in targets:
...     for e in exprs:
...         m = regex.match(rf"(?:{e}){{d}}", t)
...         """
>>>
>>> cprof.run(regex_script)
         57912 function calls (57835 primitive calls) in 0.180 seconds
...
>>> regex_script = """
... for t in targets:
...     for e in exprs:
...         m = regex.match(rf"(?:{e}){{d}}", t, flags=regex.ENHANCEMATCH)
...         """
>>> 
>>> cprof.run(regex_script)
         57904 function calls (57827 primitive calls) in 0.298 seconds
```

Performance is a little better than the `partial_match()` solution without the `regex.ENHANCEMATCH` flag. However it's slower with the flag.

regex with the `regex.BESTMATCH` flag is probably most similar to `partial_match()` in behavior, but it is even slower:

```
>>> regex_script = """
... for t in targets:
...     for e in exprs:
...         m = regex.match(rf"(?:{e}){{d}}", t, flags=regex.BESTMATCH)
...         """
>>> cprof.run(regex_script)
         57912 function calls (57835 primitive calls) in 0.338 seconds
```

`regex` also has a `partial=True` flag, but this doesn't seem to work at all like we'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with any regex library that I know of, but it is possible if you have access to the state machine and step through it one character at a time.

Compiling the regex to the state machine is a little tricky, but running the state machine is trivial, so you can do whatever sort of stepping you want. As an example, [mine is here](https://github.com/o11c/nicate/blob/master/src/mre_run.c)

This could tell you after how many characters it switches from "might match depending on future input" to "does not match due to conflict," but not directly a percentage (though I don't think that's really what you want).